# Javascript Regular Expressions: obtain last two segments, divided by a dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable value that can have multiple segments separated by a dot. For example:

```
var value = "abc.def.hij.asd.local"
```

When the variable is passed in I don't know how many segments it will have. It can have 3 or more. For example:

```
var value1 = "abc.cda.bds";
var value2 = "fdf.sdfsdf.dsds.sdfsdf.sdfds";
```

How do I use regular expressions in Javascript to get only the last two segments. For example:

```
var value1 = "asda.dfgd.ghghg.hjkhj";
// return "ghghg.hjkhj"

var value2 = "dfgdf.fghfg.fgfh";
// return "ghfg.fgfh"
```

Comment: What have you tried? What have you learned about regular expressions so far that might help you with this?

Comment: I have just tried this and this works as well

Comment: i have tried this, and this works as well
function ModifyVar(VarVal) {
    var Val = VarVal;
    var arr = Val .split('.');
    var regxval = Val.replace(Val, arr[arr.length - 2] + '.' + arr[arr.length - 1]);
    return regxval;
}

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.match` function.

```
string.match(/[^.]*\.[^.]*$/)
```

**Example:**

```
> var s = "dfgdf.fghfg.fgfh"
undefined
> s.match(/[^.]*\.[^.]*$/)[0]
'fghfg.fgfh'
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using regex:

```
var s = 'asda.dfgd.ghghg.hjkhj';
var arr = s.split('.');
var result = arr[arr.length-2] + '.' + arr[arr.length-1];
//=> ghghg.hjkhj
```